# How to retrieve error when launching sqlcmd from C# Code?

Tags: c#

I use sqlcmd to run large script SQL from C# code:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("sqlcmd", @" -S . -i "+ currentDBScript.Value + " -b");
 
info.UseShellExecute = false;
//No new window is required
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
//The windows style will be hidden
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
//The output will be read by the starndar output process
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = info;

//Start the process
proc.Start();
```

Note that `currentDBScript.Value` is the path of my file script

I want to catch error if script executed by sqlcmd didn't succeed.

Comment: I don't  think that sqlcmd has been built with the capability to talk directly with extern application, but you can ask it to write a log file that you can parse for errors. An example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025374/sqlcmd-command-how-to-save-output-into-log-file

Comment: otherwise you create a batch file which interacts with sqlcmd commands where you can capture the errors and throw exceptions, (info.StandardError.ReadToEnd()) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795430/error-handling-with-batch-file-sqlcmd

Comment: I've used same code lots of times and it should work.  You need the full path of the SQLCMD.EXE unless it is in same folder and the c# executable.